# Windows Live Mail CSV import skips contacts?

Tags: windows-7, email, csv

I'm trying to import my Google Contacts into Windows Live Mail.   I have 194 contacts exported as an "Outlook CSV" from Google Contacts, but when I import them into Windows Live Mail contacts, only 136 show up.   I'm guessing that WLM skips some rows because it's "unhappy" with the data, but I can't figure out which column it doesn't like.

I should add that the contacts that are missing are scattered throughout the file, and don't appear to fit any pattern.   Also, no errors show up on the screen - the import completes fine, it just doesn't pick up all the contacts.

Anyone run into this before, and how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same thing.
The VCF file I had was exported from Apple's icloud.com.

Only about 1/2 of the contacts were importing into Windows Contacts.

I finally figured out that the line separator used in the VCF file is just LF, rather than CR-LF, which Windows uses/prefers.

I opened the file in Notepad++ and searched for \n and replaced with \r\n, saved it, and every entry imported.

Comment: OP is asking about Gmail and Windows Live